# issue in post Tastypie

Tags: tastypie

When trying to POST data to my tastypie api, I always get error code 401, even when using the Django admin account for authentication and authorization. My Django server is running as development server through "python manage.py runserver IP"

I'm using the latest master-branch of tastypie and Django 1.4.3

### here are parts of my api.py

```
class QueueResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Queue.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'queue'
        ]
```

---

### my curl command:

```
curl --dump-header  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"qid": "4", "msg": "An error occured!"}' http://IP/api/fail/
```

---

### the corresponding error message:

```
HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2013 19:16:00 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

---

Does anyone of you has an idea why I'm getting this error code?

Answer (score 2):

You should define authorization that you will use in the meta class of the resource.

Default one is ReadOnlyAuthorization.
More info you can find [Here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like what UnLiMiTeD said, you need to define [Authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html).

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
class QueueResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = Queue.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'queue'
```

This will make the `QueueResource` have no authorization restrictions. You can post to it without verifying any credentials.

The default authorization method is a `ReadOnlyAuthorization`.